# Cannot navigate between Angular 2 project files using WebStorm

Tags: angular, webstorm

Just updated my project and import the old file structure used the following:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
rmdir /S/Q node_modules dist
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
npm install
```

The project is running while using `ng serve`. When I'm trying to navigate between project files using <kbd>Ctrl + Click</kbd>, WebStorm is not recognize the component/html files I need to search them manually.

Is there a way to scan to component for fast navigation as I had before?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone will face the same problem:

The problem was that I did not have the angular.js file for the uncompressed version, quick solution: https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/03/angularjs-workflow-in-webstorm/

download the uncomppressed version, Inside webstorem click ctrl + alt + s, Javascript | Libaries | add file, and the angular.js file click ok. it will work.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, but I use WebStorm 2017.1 for Mac OS. Are you using this version or the older one?

Cmd-click on the html file in the template opens that file.  Go to Preferences | TypeSript and make sure that the checkbox Use TypeScript Service is selected and under the Configure button Use Angular Service is selected.

Comment: Just updated my question with an additional pic, that might be the problem? i dont have the user angular service...

Comment: It seems that you have an older version of WebStorm.